# Prolog - partially ordered set

Tags: prolog

There is a partially ordered set relation `le(X,Y)`, when Y mod X = 0 
(so there are `le(1,5), le(5,70), le(7,14)` etc.)

I have to make predicates 
`max(X)` is X maximum element
`greatest(X)` is X the greatest element

defining `max(X)` is simple, because
`max(X) :- \+ le(X,A), le(B,X)`. (there isn't any greater element and X is in set)

But how about `greatest(X)`?

Comment: What is the difference between maximum and greatest?

Comment: By the way, I don't think your `max(X)` works. If you type in `max(X)` it just fails with no result for `X`.

Comment: Greatest(X) - maximum(X) and there is no maximum(Y) (Y=/=X)

Comment: your question is super hard to understand.

Comment: And typically predicate "le" is used to represent "less equal" in prolog clp community .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [least upper bound](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastUpperBound.html) (LUB), you need two sets. First the argument set S, that you are asking for the LUB, and then the partial order T where you are searching for the LUB. So input is as follows:

- T the partial order
- S the set, S subset T

The code is then very similar as for the max. Just use range restricted formulas, that search over the partial order. This works in ordinary Prolog for finite partial orders.

Here is your divisibility example:

```
?- [user].
ls(X,Y) :- 
    Y mod X =:= 0.
bound(M,Y) :- 
    \+ (member(X,M), 
        \+ls(X,Y)).
lub(S,T,Y) :-  
    member(Y,T), bound(S,Y), 
    \+ (member(Z,T), bound(S,Z), 
        \+ls(Y,Z)).
^D
```

And here are some example runs:

```
?- lub([3,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],Y).
Y = 6 ;
false.

?- lub([5,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],Y).
false.

?- lub([5,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],Y).
Y = 15 ;
false.
```

The above very general algorithm is not the efficientest, it is of order m^2*n^2, where n is the size of S and m is the size of T. For infinite partial orders you would need to invent something with CLP(X).